# how to eliminate with ajax and laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to delete a column using ajax and laravel so far I have the following but it does not work for me thanks,

I send a route to the post, this route I get from the path attribute of the button

view()

```
<button id="eliminarArticulo" ruta = "{{URL::to('auto/eliminarArticulo')}}" onclick="eliminarArticulo({{$detalle_modelo->idetalleModelo}})" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

js(ajax)

```
   <script>

        function  eliminarArticulo(id) {

             var ruta = $('#eliminarArticulo').attr('ruta');
             var url = ruta+"/"+id;

          //   alert(url)

            $.post({
                url: url,
                data: {id:id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function (res) {
                   // console.log(res);
                }
            });

        }

</script>
```

Ruta

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auto'], function(){
    Route::get('crear', 'AutoController@crear')->name('auto.crear');
  Route::post('registrar', 'AutoController@registrar')->name('auto.registrar');
    Route::get('listar', 'AutoController@listar')->name('auto.listar');
    Route::get('editar/{cod}', 'AutoController@editar')->name('auto.editar');
    Route::post('actualizar', 'AutoController@actualizar')->name('auto.actualizar');
    Route::get('ver/{cod}', 'AutoController@ver')->name('auto.ver');
    Route::post('guardarArticulo', 'AutoController@guardarArticulo')->name('auto.guardarArticulo');
    Route::get('editarArticulo/{cod}', 'AutoController@editarArticulo')->name('auto.editarArticulo');
    Route::post('actualizarArticulo', 'AutoController@actualizarArticulo')->name('auto.actualizarArticulo');
    Route::post('ActualizarEstadoAuto/{cod}', 'AutoController@ActualizarEstadoAuto')->name('auto.ActualizarEstadoAuto');
    Route::post('eliminarArticulo/{cod}', 'AutoController@eliminarArticulo')->name('auto.eliminarArticulo');

});
```

controlador

```
 public function eliminarArticulo(Request $request){

      return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please feel free to correct my grammar because it's terrible**

This is how I made my ajax delete function.

When the user clicks on the button it will trigger the onclick event I'm passing in the Id with `onclick="deleteRmaMarketplace({{ $rmaMarketplace->id }})`.

Here is my button once the user clicks on the button it will call the `deleteRmaMarketplace()` function also note that I'm passing the MarketplaceId into the function parameters like this `deleteRmaMarketplace({{ $rmaMarketplace->id }})`

```
<button class="btn btn-danger rm-marketplace" type="button" onclick="deleteRmaMarketplace({{ $rmaMarketplace->id }})">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
 </button>`
```

Here is my route I'm using named routes because it's easier and I'll use the named routes for my JavaScript variable.

```
Route::post('/rma-returnType-delete', 'AdminSettings\AdminSettingsController@rmaReturnTypeDelete')->name('admin.rma.returnType.delete');
```

Here is the JavaScript function I made  first I made a variable called `deleteRmaReturnTypeUrl` and I gave it the value of my route like this `'{{ route('admin.rma.returnType.delete') }}';` I can use this for the Url in the ajax function next I made a variable called `token`  and I gave it the value of the `'{{ csrf_token() }}';` you'll need it because all post requests required the token in laravel

```
   var deleteRmaReturnTypeUrl  = '{{ route('admin.rma.returnType.delete') }}';
   var token                   = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

    function deleteRmaMarketplace(Id) {
        $.ajax({
            url:        deleteRmaMarketplaceUrl,
            type:       'post',
            data:       {Id: Id, _token: token},
            dataType:   'json',
            success:function () {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my controller code

First, we check if the request is ajax and then I make a variable called `$ticketId` and give it the value of the Id we posted from the ajax request next I made a variable `$ticket` and I get the `RmaReturnType` where the `id = to the ticketId variable` then we delete the ticket by calling `$ticket->delete()` and then we return the `response`

```
public function rmaReturnTypeDelete(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $ticketId = $request->input('Id');

        $ticket = RmaReturnType::where('id', $ticketId)->firstOrFail();

        $ticket->delete();

        return response()->json($ticket);
    }

    return response()->json('error', 422);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I added token and work it  but I think that  the token not necesary because I not use form, why is necesaty the token ? thanks

Comment: @robertpopi because you're making a post request

Comment: @robertpopi  This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

Comment: @robertpopi no problem and if you liked my answer please accept it :)